# Get Emails from Gmail Inbox which does not have specific label attached to it using Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

In my Gmail inbox, emails are coming from a specific email address on a daily basis. I have a script that gets data from them and then attaches a specific label to them. As the emails are increasing day by day, the run time of the script is also increasing. I am looking for a solution that checks the following conditions before processing the email/conversation:

**1. It is coming from a specific email address?**

**2. There should not be any label attached to it**

Here is the sample script right now:

```
function checkEmailsFromSpecificAddress() {

  var emailAddress = "example@google.com"; // Replace with the desired email address
  var processedMail= GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label Attached");
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:' + emailAddress);

  if(threads.length>0){

 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    threads[i].addLabel(processedMail).refresh();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
         
        //Get the required data

    }
   }
  }
 }
```

I want the script to consider only those emails where the label is not attached. I have one more question:

**3. The above script adds a label to a thread, if we devise a method that would overlook the thread where the label is attached, does that mean that every new email coming into that thread would not be processed as well? If yes, then how to avoid it?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Labels are not attached to messages. They’re attached to threads.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your 3 questions, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your questions and my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my understanding of your question was not correct. In this case, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill.

Comment: @EagleEye And, unfortunately, I cannot understand `My question was, If the new email comes into a thread where the label is already attached, that means the script will ignore the thread and will not process the new email, hope I was clear enough.`. By this, I cannot think of a solution to your actual question. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your actual question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: thank you for assistance, please ignore 3rd question, we can narrow it down, Can we develop a script that would check if there is no label attached to the thread?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your question of `Can we develop a script that would check if there is no label attached to the thread?`, in this case, how about using `has:nouserlabels` to the search query as I proposed in my deleted answer? In this case, only the threads that have no labels are obtained. If you want to retrieve only the threads that have labels, please use `has:userlabels` instead of `has:nouserlabels`. If my understanding of your new question, I apologize, again.